# android set ExpadableListview height dynamically

Tags: android, height, expandablelistview, parameters

i have `ExpandableListview` inside `ScrollView` and i know that's not good but i had too, the only solution to show the whole list is by set its height by code using `layoutParams`

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
ExpandableListViewData.length());

i came up with a solution that every time i expand a group of the list am gonna change the height to fit with new height

this solution is good but i can't figure a Fixed Value for height to give to the Params at the first time, SO is there a way to know the actual size from the size of the array

Comment: It's a little hard to tell exactly what your problem is from the information given, but I'm going to take a stab and say that you should create your own class which expands ExpandableListView and overrides the onMeasure() method, returning the appropriate size.

Comment: i have ExpandableListView in a ScrollView, and if i try to open the list it will expand but because its inside a scrolView it will expand without expanding the ScrolView(its like the scrolView doesn't recognize it as list ), so the only solution here is that everytime i expand the list i have to change its height to fit the expanded height, but the value i use here is not fixed, so i want to know if i can know the height of arraylist that i fill the expandableListView with corresponding to screen height